# RoR Ransack how to add own sql + form option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have an sql query in RoR: 
`"DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() ,'%m-%d')= DATE_FORMAT(#{field_name} ,'%m-%d')"` 
for searching users that have birthdays today.
I want to add it to ransack form, to be chosen on webpage. Tried `Ransack.configure` but I can't get how implement in it custom sql. Is it possible and what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take the user input in the form and pass pass it to controller -> model.

Then go with below approach to fetch your query result & return the response to view.

```
query = "select * from employers where id = #{employer_id}"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all query
```